# How do I correctly redirect after update in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The table seems to update, but it does not redirect me to the main page. I have try different things with no luck. If anyone can help me. Thans you in advance. I will put the update code only, if there is need to put the complete code of the page I will.

```
$id_actividades = $_GET['idactividades'];

include('../includes/eamoschema.php');

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades WHERE idactividades=:id_actividades");

$stmt -> bindParam(':id_actividades', $id_actividades);
  $stmt->execute();

     $result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);





  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== 'POST'){
if (isset($_POST['tname']) || isset($_POST['place']) || isset($_POST['organizer']) || isset($_POST['from']) || isset($_POST['to']) ) { 

   $tname = $_POST['tname'];
  $place = $_POST['place'];
$organizer = $_POST['organizer'];
$from = $_POST['from'];    
$to = $_POST['to'];

    try{

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE guaynabodb.actividades SET ntorneo = :n_torneo, ltorneo = :l_torneo, otorneo = :o_torneo, fecha_inicial = :from, fecha_final = :to WHERE idactividades=:id_actividades");
 $stmt -> bindParam(':n_torneo', $tname);
  $stmt -> bindParam(':l_torneo', $place);
   $stmt -> bindParam(':o_torneo', $organizer);
    $stmt -> bindParam(':from', $from);
     $stmt -> bindParam(':to', $to);
     $stmt -> bindParam(':id_actividades', $id_actividades);


 $stmt->execute();


 }
 catch (PDOException $ex) {

 $_SESSION['errorCode3'] =$ex->getMessage();
 header('Location: actividades.php?errorCode=3');//To redirect
 exit;
 }

header('Location:actividades.php');//To redirect
  exit;
}
  }
```

Comment: Is there a possibility that you are sending output, ie. there is a space before your open php tag -> `_<?php`, as `header()` will not redirect if headers are already sent

Comment: Did you get an error message like this => `headers already sent`?

Comment: *"but it does not redirect me to the main page"* - What is the main page?

Comment: actividades.php I don't get any headers already sent error

Comment: I verified the tags and the look good.

Comment: Any chance this could be an issue with not having a space after `Location:` in the code?  I'm not sure how the browser responds without the space as I've never tried it.

Comment: BTW, what's the logic in your indentation scheme? It's very difficult to follow.

Comment: try javascript redirect echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>'; something like this

Comment: For some reason maybe I was to sleepy yesterday I did not spot the first tag witch was sending output I deleted the space between the tag and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **BIGGEST** and **foremost** problem is **lack of error reporting.**

It spoils you not only in this particular case but your whole experience with PHP.
Every time when something goes wrong, PHP will tell you - what happened and whom to blame. Only if you let it. But you don't.

On a live site you have to peek into error logs, so, you have to configure PHP this way:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',0);
ini_set('log_errors',1);
```

while on a local development server it's all right to make errors on screen:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
```

As soon as you will have your error, you will know what to do: just search its text on Google. You will find an answer immediately, as it's most popular PHP error message ever.

Comment: For some reason maybe I was to sleepy yesterday I did not spot the first php tag witch was sending output. I deleted the space between the tag and that's it.